# Run curl command on each line of a file and fetch data from result

Tags: regex, bash, curl, awk

Suppose I have a file containing a list of links of webpages.

```
www.xyz.com/asdd
www.wer.com/asdas
www.asdas.com/asd
www.asd.com/asdas
```

I know that doing `curl www.xyz.com/asdd` will fetch me the html of that webpage. I want to fetch some data from that webpage.

So the scenario is use curl to hit all the links in the file one by one and extract some data from the webpage and store somewhere else. Any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `while read line; do curl "$line"; done < your_file`? It will loop through the lines and `curl` on each one. For the rest of requirements, it is not very clear what you mean.

Comment: `use curl to hit all the links in the file` You would have to parse the file first.

Comment: @fedorqui exactly after hitting each line i want to extract say title of the page using a regex may be

Comment: That's kind of another question. What have you tried?

Comment: ooo @fedorqui your command did the job for me thanks a lot. add it as an answer i ll accept

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, this will loop through `your_file` and `curl` each line:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
   curl "$line"
done < your_file
```

To get the `<title>` of a page, you can `grep` something like this:

```
grep -iPo '(?<=<title>).*(?=</title>)' file
```

So all together you could do

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
   curl -s "$line" | grep -Po '(?<=<title>).*(?=</title>)'
done < your_file
```

Note `curl -s` is for silent mode. See an example with google page:

```
$ curl -s http://www.google.com | grep -Po '(?<=<title>).*(?=</title>)'
302 Moved
```

Comment: what does the -P do in the grep ?

Comment: `-P` allows `grep` to perform Perl regular expressions, like the one I used to match a string in between `<title>` and `</title>`. You can read more about it in http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: if you;re here in 2023 and getting headaches about why a simple `curl -O "$line"` is giving errors like `curl: Failed to extract a sensible file name from the URL to use for storage!` and `curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL` - check the line endings in the source file (my text files were set to CRLF, they parsed fine when set to LF)

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this in just one line with `xargs`. Let's say you have a file in the working directory with all your URLs (one per line) called `sitemap`

`xargs -I{} curl -s {} <sitemap | grep title`

This would extract any lines with the word "title" in it. To extract the title tags you'll want to change the `grep` a little. The `-o` flag ensures that only the grepped result is printed:

`xargs -I{} curl -s {} <sitemap | grep -o "<title>.*</title>"`

A couple of things to note:

- If you want to extract certain data, you will need to `\` escape characters.

  - For HTML attributes for example, you should match single and double quotes, and escape them like `[\"\']`
- Sometimes, depending on the character set, you may get some unusual `curl` output with special characters. If you detect this, you'll need to switch the encoding with a utility like `iconv`